# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me aparezca un mapa creado en R al hacer Knit?

Tags: markdown

Hola a todo el mundo,

Estoy utilizando este código para crear un mapa, y se me crea sin problema en el Markdown.

```
THOR_map <- THOR |> 
  filter(!is.na(LONGITUDE) & !is.na(LATITUDE)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), 
                             agr = "constant") %>% 
  st_set_crs(4269)
tmap_mode("view")
THOR_map %>% 
  filter(TGT_COUNTRY %in% c("GERMANY"), AIRCRAFT_NAME %in% c("B17")) %>% 
  tm_shape() +
  tm_dots()
```

Sin embargo, al knitear, el espacio donde sale el mapa está vacío, y me sale el siguiente error: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano!